# change update drop down append result on on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show search result in drop down list - once the keyword changes want to update the drop down result - but once the first result is appearing its not disappearing on keyup though the result appearing below the initial result

e.g-

if I typre "a"
results -

- abc
- abb
- acc

again if  I am typing "ac"
result that showing

- abc
- abb
- acc
- acc

Where only

- acc
  need to show

**here is my javascript code**

```
   for(i=0; i <results.length; i++){
   $('#list_id').append('<li><a href="">'+results[i].get("name")+'</a</li>');                       
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your element before going through the loop

Use:

```
$('#list_id').html('');
for(i=0; i <results.length; i++){
   $('#list_id').append('<li><a href="">'+results[i].get("name")+'</a</li>');                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your list on every `keyup`.

For example:

```
$('.searchbox').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#list_id').html('');
  for(i=0; i <results.length; i++){
   $('#list_id').append('<li><a href="">'+results[i].get("name")+'</a</li>');
  }
});
```